# Are there still cases when we would still use non-generic collections?

Tags: .net

Besides the obvious reason of storing any type as an object and storing it in a non-generic collection, what other reasons are there for still using non-generic collections.

As of yet I have found no other purpose, other than backward compatibility with older software, for even keeping these types of collections in the .NET framework.

It seems like it would just create more work, because you're constantly boxing and un-boxing from type object to it's original type and vice-versa.

Also you run into the issue of sometimes not remembering what the original datatype of the object was to begin with (eg Double, Float, Decimal). This in fact has to be one of the problems I used to run into when developing in PHP.

Type safety seems like the way to go when developing modern-day applications, as I have created quite a few already and have never been forced to use any of them (non-generic collections).

Or maybe there are other reasons I'm not aware of that make these collections necessary? Obviously there included when trying to pass the certification exam for .NET for a reason. Just not sure why. Could someone please shed light on this subject?

Comment: The term "non-generic collections" is a bit of a catch all.  There are times when you want to create a collection for a particular type, making that collection non-generic.  Under the hood however, it may use a `List<T>`.  I suppose you are referring to `ArrayList` vs `List<T>` or `Hashtable` vs `Dictionary<K, T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very few reasons to do this.

About the only argument I see, on occasion, to use one of the non-generic collections is that there is a potential performance difference in `Hashtable` vs. `Dictionary<object,object>`.  This is really due to a difference in implementation, which is [described in detail on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28VS.80%29.aspx).

That being said, I'd still typically use `Dictionary<T,U>` - unless there was a very specific reason that `Hashtable` was providing some type of advantage, and this advantage could be proven via measurements on a real dataset.  Overall, the performance is similar enough that I've rarely found issues in real world implementations.  In most of my testing, `Dictionary<T,U>` outperforms `Hashtable` (which, I'm sure, was also Microsoft's findings, hence they decided to change to a chaining based implementation), but there are some cases when `Hashtable` can be faster.

Comment: Yeah I read something from Microsoft that said generics generally perform better than non-generic collections. I have yet to find an occurance where it's the opposite. It took more code to create a boxing/unboxing class for my types when I could simply use a generic collection and avoid the hassle. Plus we got the compiler looking after us when we use generics.

Comment: @loyalpenguin: If you're using value types, generics will always perform better (due to boxing).  If the key and value are a class, Hashtable, in theory, will potentially have different performance characteristics when hash collisions occur, which means it could, theoretically, do better - in practice, though, I treat all non-generic collections as obsolete.

Comment: Another facet of the `Dictionary<K,V>` vs `Hashtable` debate is that `Hashtable` is partially thread-safe out-of-the-box, so you can use multiple readers/single writer with no locking, and mr/mw only requires synchronisation of the writing threads. It's not so much of an issue now that .NET4 provides `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` etc, but I've used this in the past for fast, thread-safe, (almost) lock-free caches (although only ever for ref types, and always wrapped within a generic facade of some kind).

Answer (score 3):

I know of no reason other than legacy or third party support, basically, when you are forced to use them.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking. I can't see why you would want you would use them in any modern day application (.NET +2). Although it brings up another interesting question: Why do developers work in environments that don't follow this model to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, I have never used non-generic collections since .NET 2.0 - only when I needed to demonstrate boxing or similar.

One use case could be having a collection which contains **heterogeneous** items although you can always use `List<object>` instead.